# Javascript only: Function renders a dropdown and table where the value from the dropdown is needed to filter the table

Tags: javascript, html, dom, drop-down-menu

I created a function which renders a dropdown and a table. This dropdown gives me values which I use inside the function to filter the table. For some reason, it does not update when I reselect something on the dropdown.

No frameworks please thank you!

Here are some screenshots:
[image: Displays based on date range]
It does not update the columns showed because when I console.log() the values from the dropdown it does not update. It still says 1 5 but when I click the second one it should say 2 5.
[image]
I selected the second option on the dropdown. I have no idea how to do this. Sorry, I'm a beginner.

```
//function which we will use to hide and unhide rows
function toggleClass(element, className, toSet) {
    element.classList[toSet ? 'add' : 'remove'](className);
}
//The table is already rendered and when the buttons on the screen are clicked, this pagination function is called
function columnPagination(input) {
    var table = document.getElementById("tablePrint"),
    dataRows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr'),
    listHTML = "";
    //get date labels for dropdown
    var filterDateLabels = [];
    var columns = table.getElementsByTagName('th');
    for(var ii = 0; ii < columns.length; ii++){
        if(ii%input==0){
            filterDateLabels.push(columns[ii].innerHTML.slice(21,33));
        }
        if(ii%input==input-1){
            filterDateLabels.push(columns[ii].innerHTML.slice(21,33));
        }
    }
    //display dropdown with values which you will use to filter the table
    listHTML += "<select id=\"pagenumber\")>";
    for(var ii = 0; ii < filterDateLabels.length; ii++){
        listHTML += "<option value = \"" + ii + "\">" + filterDateLabels[ii] + " - ";
        if(filterDateLabels[ii+1]!= ""){
            listHTML += filterDateLabels[ii+1] + "</option>";
            ii++;
        }
        else{
            listHTML+="LAST </select>";
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('dates').innerHTML = listHTML;
    var multiplier = document.getElementById('pagenumber').value;
    multiplier = multiplier/2;
    if(multiplier == 0){
        multiplier = 1;
    }
    //hiding function which works but doesn't update when the dropdown is clicked
    input = input*multiplier;
    console.log(multiplier, input);
    for (var i = 0; i < dataRows.length; i++) {
        var cells = dataRows[i].children;
        for (var cell = 0; cell < cells.length; cell++) {
            toggleClass(cells[cell], 'hide', cell > input)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide us with code.

Comment: @KevinKloet Done! Sorry my code is messy w/o comments. I was planning to comment on it after I fixed it. I can comment first if you want.

Comment: yes, please add some comment's that makes it easier to understand.

Comment: @KevinKloet Commented

Comment: @KevinKloet please help me

Comment: sorry for the late response. in your second screenshot there is a 404 not found error and 2 No 'acces-control-allow-resource' header is present on the requested resource error's. the 404 is of the showClasses.css file, try checking if the code does work and the classes get correctly added to the element and fix the linking of the css file.

Comment: Yeah I know those are issues but those are something else. I need to fix this one first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just using onchange="myFunction()".

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Everything you need is up there if you encounter the same issue as I did. I was having trouble because I was editing the wrong file. @KevinKloet helped me realize that by pointing out another error. Thanks!